# Rails POSTing image with button_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, post

Can anyone tell me if the following is possible, and if so, how to go about it the *Rails Way*?

I have thousands of images on my server. When a user gets to a particular resource on my Rails-based application and they need to be able to launch an external application, I can create a button like this:

```
<%= button_to('Launch application', 'http://www.foobar.com', :method => "post") %>
```

However, I need to attach a 2MB image to the POST request. The user can't upload the image themselves as they don't have access to it + it's on my server. Is there something I can add to the button_to to attach an image *housed on the server* that will be sent with the request?

Thanks in advance!

- Vanessa

Answer (score 0):

If the user doesn't have access to the resource, they can't POST it. The best you can probably do is have the user POST the form to YOU, then you build the POST request, including the desired private image, and POST it to the final destination.